# Show contents of a folder server to client C

Tags: c, file, client, server

How can I send the names of files contents in a folder from a server to a client? I would that in a client I could see the list of files contents in a folder receive from a server.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a program ready for that, would you buy it? it's documented. I don't think someone will answer this question, because it's too broad.

Comment: Please see help for what constitutes a 'good' question

Comment: Would about the "good" old NFS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)?

Comment: @alk good suggestion but I think this is homework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side:

0. socket
1. bind
2. listen
3. accept on listening socket
4. recv request via accepted socket
5. opendir, readdir, closedir
6. send dir-list
7. close accepted socket
8. start over with 4.

Client side:

0. socket
1. connect
2. send request
3. recv dir-list
4. close
5. printf dir-list

Comment: I wrote this code and it works but in the client it shows the list without newline, all in one line. How can I insert a newline after every file? Thank you.

``  
    if (dp != NULL){
                while (ep = readdir(dp))
                                 
                rv = send(conn_fd, ep->d_name, strlen(ep->d_name), 0);               
                  
                (void) closedir(dp);
            }else
                perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
             
            close(conn_fd); ``

@alk

Comment: @Heisenberg: This should become a different/new question.

Comment: ok thank you, I wrote here because I didn't want to lose your attention. Now I ask a new question. @alk

Comment: You are free to post a comment here linking the new question.

Comment: I'm a beginners, I don't know how to do. I ask a new question. Thank you for you time. @alk

Comment: After having posted the question, click on the question's "share" button, copy the link you get from this and past it here in a fresh comment.  @Heisenberg Btw: Less then an hour for a more or less working client/server pair is a promising performance for a beginner! ;-)

Comment: oh thank you! :) ... here is the link If I understood @alk
http://stackoverflow.com/q/28772357/4176761

Comment: hey wise Alk, can you say me how can I erase some type of file to the list of the file that are in the directory? thank yoy :)

Comment: @Heisenberg: This should become a different/new question. ;-)

Comment: Here it is! :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/28861544/4176761