# How to insert a newline in a recv in C

Tags: c, sockets, client

I write this code to send the list of files contents in a folder from a server for see it in a client. The code works, but I see all files without a newline. How can I see the files with a newline or space? 
For example, now I see: "file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt" and I would see "file1.txt 
file2.txt file3.txt"

Thank you!

```
DIR *dp;           
int rv, stop_received;       
struct dirent *ep;           

dp = opendir ("./");
char *newline="\n";  
if (dp != NULL) {
    while (ep = readdir(dp))                      
        rv = send(conn_fd, ep->d_name, strlen(ep->d_name), 0);               

    (void)closedir(dp);
} else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");           
close(conn_fd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, declare a newline like this

```
char newline = '\n';
```

and send it

```
rv = send(conn_fd, &newline, 1, 0);
```

So if you want to send the directory name and a newline after it, do it this way

```
char newline;

newline = '\n';
while (ep = readdir(dp))
{
    size_t length;

    length = strlen(ep->d_name);
    rv     = send(conn_fd, ep->d_name, length, 0); 
    if (rv != length)
        pleaseDoSomething_ThereWasAProblem();
    rv = send(conn_fd, &newline, 1, 0);
   /* ... continue here ... */
}
```

Comment: You might like to tell the guy when/where to send it?

Comment: And propably one should better recommed to send a CR/LF (`"\r\n"`) which more or less is the standard for net-apps.

Comment: It doesn't work. For the compilator the error is "size_t length;" in the while.

Comment: @Heisenberg include `stdlib.h` or change `size_t` to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Excuse but Is it normal that it show also some points at the end or in the beginning of the list?

Comment: @Heisenberg hello, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I see the content of the folder, but in the beginning or at the end of the list of the files I see some points (like this ....). Is it normal or is there an error in my code? Thank you :)

Comment: It is normal, you just need to skip them with something like `if ((strcmp(name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(name, "..") == 0)) continue;`, they are the current and previous directory respectively and will be present in every directory.