# Show only some contents of a folder in a client/server in C

Tags: c, file, client, server

I'm developing a client/server program in C where I want to see the file contents in a folder. The program works, but I would to see only a .txt file, not all the files. How can I do this? Thank you!

```
DIR *dp;           
int rv,rv1,stop_received,nread2;       
struct dirent *ep;   
char buffer[300],appoggio[1000],buffer2[300];    
        dp = opendir ("./");
        if (dp != NULL){
            while (ep = readdir(dp)){
               if ((strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") == 0) 
|| (strcmp(ep->d_name,"..") == 0) 
|| (strcmp(ep->d_name, "SERVERD.c\0") == 0)
||(strcmp(ep->d_name, "h") == 0)
|| (strcmp(ep->d_name, "Menù segreteria") == 0)
||(strcmp(ep->d_name, "Menù docente") == 0)) 
continue;
           strcpy(buffer,ep->d_name);
           strcat(buffer,"\n");
           send(conn_fd, buffer,strlen(buffer), 0);   

            }
            (void) closedir(dp);
        }else
            perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another condition to the ones that call `continue:

```
|| ((4 <= strlen(ep->d_name)) && (strstr(ep->d_name, ".txt") == (ep->d_name + strlen(ep->d_name) - 4)))
```

Note: The `4` is derived from the number of characters in `".txt"`.

Note^2: The way the above test is coded if far from being efficient. Calling `strlen()` two time on the same "string" for example is not nice.